# DB Laravel Query, get a datagroup in join for each data

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I am using Laravel, I would like to know how I can obtain this result using DB::

```
[{'id':1,'name':'A',pictures:[{'property_id':1,'filename':'A01'},{'property_id':1,'filename':'A02'},{'property_id':1,'filename':'A03'}]}]
```

Right now I'm using eloquent relationships and it works fine but it's slow so I want to do it directly with DB::

PROPERTIES

[image]

PICTURES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it necesary to make it exactly in that format?
To just get all data you want as one object try something like:

```
DB::table('properties')
    ->join('pictures', 'property_id', 
'=', 'properties.id')
    ->select('*')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: yes, because I need just one object per property, and doing like you it give me 3 objects of the same property with the pictures something like this: [{'id':1,'name':'A', 'property_id':1,'filename':'A01'},{'id':1,'name':'A','property_id':1,'filename':'A02'},{'id':1,'name':'A','property_id':1,'filename':'A03'}]